# How to test if a dictionary contains a specific key?

Tags: python

What's the cleanest way to test if a dictionary contains a key?

```
x = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
if (x.contains_key('a')):
    ....
```

Comment: The [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is your friend.

Comment: -1 due to duplicate question.

Comment: @Steven - I believe duplicates are helpful, because they make this question easier to find. I did search before I posted, and didn't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ripper234: This closed question will indeed make it easier for future searches to find the answered question, but that doesn't make the question all that valuable in and of itself.

Comment: @Steven - "all that valuable" - valuable enough not to get -1 votes, even if not valuable enough for +1. That's just IMHO of course, you're free to vote as you wish :)

Comment: @ripper234: My ratio of up votes to down votes is currently 194 to 10.  You didn't search hard enough, hence the -1.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski "you didn't search hard enough" -- why do you want to make people search harder?  I vote for easier searching over harder searching every time.

Comment: @JonCrowell:  Enter the title of this question into Google and you will find that most of the top hits address his question.  That's why I downvoted it.  3 other people agreed while 26 disagreed and gave an upvote.  My opinion does not always fit in with the majority, but I'm not the only voter.  The system works.  If you disagree with my votes, just vote the opposite.

Answer (score 702):

```
'a' in x
```

and a quick search reveals some nice information about it: http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: It may be obvious to some, but you can use this with `if 'a' in x:`.

Comment: `'a' in x` or `'a' not in x` is good.

Comment: @ripper234 just came across this and it helped a lot, but I was wondering - are you able to accept the answer now, 4.5yrs later?:) Or it can't be marked anymore due to the duplicate label?

Comment: [This is a better link IMHO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping)